# Split the returned data by date

Tags: javascript, dom, data-structures, rendering

I return my form as follows, in which I have two expected results for the 12th and two expected results for the 13th.

```js
var data = [{
    Designacao: "Micro-ondas1",
    Capitulo: "Cozinha",
    Data: "2023-08-12",
  },
  {
    Designacao: "Exaustor cinzento 1",
    Capitulo: "",
    Data: "2023-08-12",
  },
  {
    Designacao: "Mesa - Castanha -8 Lugares",
    Capitulo: "Sala",
    Data: "2023-08-13"
  },
  {
    Designacao: "cama",
    Capitulo: "Quarto",
    Data: "2023-08-13",
  },
];

var linha = ``;

Object.keys(data).forEach(i => {

  Designacao = data[i].Designacao;
  Capitulo = data[i].Capitulo;
  Data = data[i].Data;

  if (Data != Data) {
    linha += `<div class="card-header">Data Passagem de Turno - ${Data}</div>`;
  }

  linha += `<div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="form-label">Data </p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dataen" value="${Data}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <p class="form-label">Código Utente </p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoen" value="${Capitulo}" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <p class="form-label">Diário de Enfermagem </p>
              <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" name="didiarenf" > ${Designacao} </textarea>
            </div>`;

  $(".histpturno").html(linha);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="histpturno"></div>
```

I intend to separate the results by day. For example, before the first result of the 12th, show the header that is inside the if and then only show the header again when the results of the 13th are returned

I tried to achieve the expected with the if, but it doesn't work, it never returns the header. The header I'm referring to is this one inside the if:

```
<div class="card-header">Data Passagem de Turno - ${Data}</div>
```

Comment: Your if statement is comparing the `Data` to itself, which is always true. You need to create and initialize a variable outside of the `foreach` that tracks the current date, compare to that in your if statement, and update it when it changes.

Comment: The OP might consider an approach which does not try to achieve everything at once, but would separate the data (re)structuring task from the (final) render task. Thus, the actually needed solution is in need of grouping and collecting data-items by any item's same date, which e.g. could be achieved via [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)ing the source data array into an object/index with same date-values as grouping keys. The reduced data-structure then is the base for the render process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if(Data != Data)`

Should be pretty obvious how that will never be true, no? `Data` is not going to change between the two read accesses on either side of the comparison operator here.

You need to compare the *current* value, with that of the *previous* record you processed. Easiest, if you store the previous value into a variable, that you initialize with a value that won't occur in the actual data (so that the check will return true on the first record already).

```js
var data = [{
    Designacao: "Micro-ondas1",
    Capitulo: "Cozinha",
    Data: "2023-08-12",
  },
  {
    Designacao: "Exaustor cinzento 1",
    Capitulo: "",
    Data: "2023-08-12",
  },
  {
    Designacao: "Mesa - Castanha -8 Lugares",
    Capitulo: "Sala",
    Data: "2023-08-13"
  },
  {
    Designacao: "cama",
    Capitulo: "Quarto",
    Data: "2023-08-13",
  },
];

var linha = ``;
var prevData = null; // initialize

Object.keys(data).forEach(i => {

  Designacao = data[i].Designacao;
  Capitulo = data[i].Capitulo;
  Data = data[i].Data;

  if (Data !== prevData) { // compare; for safety using strict type checking
    linha += `<div class="card-header">Data Passagem de Turno - ${Data}</div>`;
  }
  prevData = Data; // update, so that this will hold the correct "previous" record on the next iteration

  linha += `<div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="form-label">Data </p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dataen" value="${Data}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <p class="form-label">Código Utente </p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoen" value="${Capitulo}" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <p class="form-label">Diário de Enfermagem </p>
              <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" name="didiarenf" > ${Designacao} </textarea>
            </div>`;

  $(".histpturno").html(linha);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="histpturno"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *"The OP might consider an approach which does not try to achieve everything at once, but would separate the data (re)structuring task from the (final) render task. Thus, the actually needed solution is in need of grouping and collecting data-items by any item's same date, which e.g. could be achieved via [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)ing the source data array into an object/index with same date-values as grouping keys. The reduced data-structure then is the base for the render process."*

```js
function renderLogsFromDateIndex(rootNode, index) {
  rootNode.innerHTML = Object
    .entries(index)
    .reduce((dateItemMarkup, [date, logs]) => [

      dateItemMarkup,
      `<div class="card-header">Data Passagem de Turno - ${ date }</div>`,

      logs
        .reduce((logItemMarkup, { Data, Capitulo, Designacao }) =>

          `${ logItemMarkup }<div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="form-label">Data </p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dataen" value="${ Data }">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <p class="form-label">Código Utente </p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoen" value="${ Capitulo }" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <p class="form-label">Diário de Enfermagem </p>
              <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" name="didiarenf" > ${ Designacao } </textarea>
            </div>
          </div>`, ''
        ),

    ].join(''), '');
}

const data = [
  { Designacao: "Micro-ondas1", Capitulo: "Cozinha", Data: "2023-08-12", },
  { Designacao: "Exaustor cinzento 1", Capitulo: "", Data: "2023-08-12", },
  { Designacao: "Mesa - Castanha -8 Lugares", Capitulo: "Sala", Data: "2023-08-13" },
  { Designacao: "cama", Capitulo: "Quarto",  Data: "2023-08-13", },
];

const logsByDate = data
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.Data) - new Date(b.Data))
  .reduce((index, item) => {
    (index[item.Data] ??= []).push(item)
    return index;
  }, {});

console.log({ logsByDate });

renderLogsFromDateIndex(
  document.querySelector('.histpturno'), logsByDate
);
```

```css
.card-header {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: #eee;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="histpturno"></div>
```

Comment: @Anonimo ... The OP might have a look at the late provided, above answer.